# API design with capability of multi device and browser

Tags: api, mobile, api-design

Is there any guidelines on how to design API's for enabling capability for multi-devices(browsers, mobiles etc). For eg: In case of mobile considering the screenspace and complexities i might want to send less data for the same API call etc.

Appreciate any inputs on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For supporting both native applications on mobile devices and Web browsers I would recommend a REST API (also called Web API, or Hypermedia API). While there are many resource online, if you are new to this, I would recommend reading a book first. Try "Rest in Practice" by Jim Weber

[http://www.amazon.com/REST-Practice-Hypermedia-Systems-Architecture/dp/0596805829/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805829)

Here is a good forum to ask pragmatic REST questions:

http://groups.google.com/group/api-craft

Ferenc